# How disable screen in Android without root?

Tags: android, screen-lock

I want to disable the screen (Android 4.4.2) when I press a button. Is that possible without rooting the device? I have tried the code below, but it doesn't work (it throws exception).

`private DevicePolicyManager mDPM;`

OnCreate:

`mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);`

button listener:

`mDPM.lockNow();`

AndroidManifest.xml:

`<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
</intent-filter>`

Stack Trace:

`10-03 20:32:50.187    4172-4172/com.microchip.android.BasicAccessoryDemo_API12 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.microchip.android.BasicAccessoryDemo_API12, PID: 4172
    java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin owned by uid 10175 for policy #3
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
            at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.lockNow(IDevicePolicyManager.java:1594)
            at android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.lockNow(DevicePolicyManager.java:1076)
            at com.microchip.android.BasicAccessoryDemo_API12.PasswordActivity$1.onClick(PasswordActivity.java:209)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18471)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Comment: Post the StackTrace, and probably you just need a Permission at your AndroidManigest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a code which can lock the device (if it has code protection) and consequently to disable the screen. Below is the code.

On the Manifest put the below code:

```
   <receiver
        android:name=".MyDeviceAdminReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/my_admin" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Put this declaration in onCreate's Activity:

`static final int RESULT_ENABLE = 1;`

Put the below code in Button Listener:

```
// Enable the Administrator mode.
DevicePolicyManager deviceManger = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(
        Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE );
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(
        Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
ComponentName compName = new ComponentName( getApplicationContext( ),
        MyDeviceAdminReceiver.class);
Intent device_policy_manager_Int = new Intent( DevicePolicyManager
        .ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN );
device_policy_manager_Int.putExtra( DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,
        compName );
device_policy_manager_Int.putExtra( DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
        "Additional text explaining why this needs to be added." );
startActivityForResult( device_policy_manager_Int, RESULT_ENABLE );

// Check if the Administrator is enabled.
boolean active = deviceManger.isAdminActive(compName);

if ( active ) {
    Log.i("isAdminActive", "Admin enabled!");

    // If admin is enable - Lock device.
    deviceManger.lockNow( );
}
```